# At which fraction of light speed could I expand ten times, and 100 times, my clock's ticking?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, speed-of-light, time, time-dilation

I face this problem in special relativity: for dilating the intervals observed in an at rest,  foreign frame of reference by ten times, and also by one hundred times, how much should I reduce light speed? I. e., $c$ minus which fraction of $c$ yields such exact dilation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Lorentz transformation from your frame of reference to the reference frame moving relative to you. The calculation becomes simpler if you assume that the measurement between the clocks takes place in the same location. In that case the time dilation reduces to the following expression
$$ dt' = \frac{1}{\gamma}dt = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}dt $$
the ticking rate of the clock in the moving frame relative to you can only be less than or equal to the ticking rate in your rest frame. You can set $dt'$ to be a general fraction of $dt$ by setting
$$dt' = kdt \quad k\in(0,1]$$
such that
$$ k = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} $$
Now, if you want the clock in the moving frame to tick 10 times slower you set $k=\frac{1}{10}$ and if you want it to tick a 100 times slower you set $k=\frac{1}{100}$ and so on. All that's left to do is isolate the required relative velocity $v$ from the last equation

Comment: It might be useful to rephrase your answer in terms of $\gamma=1/k$, which is the more common relativistic parameter